# Is there a way to calculate the top 80% of marks without using if statements or inequalities?

Tags: linear-algebra

You have questions through out the course that are worth 2 (if you get it perfect), 1 or 0 marks. The professor only takes into account the top 80% of questions, for example 2/2, 2/2, 1/2, 1/2, 0/2 and only 2/2, 2/2, 1/2 would count towards your grade. You are given the number of 2's, 1's, 0's and the total amount of questions ( total # will be divisible by 5). Is there a way to calculate your grade in that course without using if statements, inequalities and recursions (only math functions like subtract, add, multiple, divide, max, min). I've been stuck on this question for a while, if you can give me a hint on how to solve this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this is a question about **Computer** Science (i.e., for http://cs.stackexchange.com, or even programming.stackexchange.com), not **Computational** Science?

Comment: This is an integer programming problem.

Comment: if you are using scripting and are looking for something simple, consider the MatLab "find" or the R "which".  They can find all indices of a vector that meet a particular criterion.

Comment: @EngrStudent: This is a question in **fundamental** computer science. You can't just fire up matlab and start running arbitrary commands. What does this answer ?

Comment: Max and min wrap a conditional and an inequality, so your choice of primitive operations seems strangely arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way? Yes, there are even Turing complete programming languages that don't have conditionals (e.g. [unlambda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unlambda)).

The most obvious way to do this would be to create a sorted list of the marks by using loops and min/max functions and then just use the first or last 80% of the entries in your list.

Comment: How will you sort a list without using inequalities?

Comment: @mabraham The OP said max and min are available. If you really can't use inequalities then those will work. (Although surely they use inequalities as part of their implementation.)